# Obj-C send and receive array over tcp sockets for iphone.

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, tcpsocket

I am trying to figure to figure out how and if you can send and recieve arrays over TCP socket. I am a bit of a newbie at objective C but I have been able to send and receive strings. I just want to get it to do arrays now.

```
 (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

NSLog(@"stream event %i", streamEvent);

switch (streamEvent) {

    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        NSLog(@"Stream opened");
        break;
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

        if (theStream == inputStream) {

            uint8_t buffer[1024];
            int len;

            while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                if (len > 0) {
                    output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                    if (nil != output) {



                        chSent = [output substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (0, 6)];

                        dimensionString = [output substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (7, 3)];
                        colorString = [output substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (7, 3)];


                         if ([chSent isEqualToString:@"dimen:"])
                        {

                            dimensionInt = [dimensionString intValue];

                        }

                        if ([chSent isEqualToString:@"color:"]) {

                           // insert array named color in here some how

                        }                                


                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;


    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

        NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
        break;

    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

        [theStream close];
        [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
       // [theStream release];
        theStream = nil;

        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Unknown event");
}
 }
```

Thats what I have. 
where I have put // insert array is where I am trying to put it

Thanks in advance if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the array data, for example integers, as a string divided by some separator,  "color:1;2;3;4;" and then just separate the strings. If you need to pass more complex data structures you can encode, send, decode. Have a look at the NSKeyedArchiver class for that.

Comment: Cool thanks, I need to send approximately 200 values in the strings I can easily do that from the sender and receiver side but is this the best way of doing it to keep the traffic down?

Comment: The best way is to optimize the data structure for sending, just send what you need. For example, don't send integers if you only need shorts... Then you need to decide if you need a "fat" receiver or not, for example, if you need to make an average, you can decide to send all the values (fat receiver), or calculate on the sender and send the result.